# Does rxjava with couchbase offer value for non-bulk opertions

Tags: java, couchbase, reactive-programming, rx-java

The new Couchbase SDK makes bulk operations easier to use and more performant use rx-java. But is there any value to using rx for operations on single values?

If we look at a simple CAS / insert operation, ie if the value exists do a cas else do an insert and return the document value

```
    final String id = "id";
    final String modified = "modified";
    final int numCasRetries = 3;

    Observable
        .defer(() -> bucket.async().get(id))
        .flatMap(document -> {
            try {
                if (document == null) {
                    JsonObject content = JsonObject.create();
                    content.put(modified,  new Date().getTime());
                    document = bucket.insert(JsonDocument.create(id, content));
                } else {
                    document.content().put(modified, new Date().getTime());
                    document = bucket.replace(document);
                }
                return Observable.just(document);
            } catch (CASMismatchException e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        })
        .retry((count, error) -> {
            // Only retry on CASMismatchException
            return ((error instanceof CASMismatchException)
                    && (count < numCASRetries));
        })
         .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
            return Observable.error(new Exception(error));
        })
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
```

So `toBlocking` will block the calling thread until a result is available. and only one value is written and read from Couchbase at a time. So I do not understand why or even if this code will be any better than

```
    final String id = "id";
    final String modified = "modified";
    final int numCasRetries = 3;

    JsonDocument document = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numCasRetries; i++) {
        document = bucket.get(id);
        try {
            if (document == null) {
                JsonObject content = JsonObject.create();
                content.put(modified,  new Date().getTime());
                document = bucket.insert(JsonDocument.create(id, content));
            } else {
                document.content().put(modified, new Date().getTime());
                document = bucket.replace(document);
            } 
            return document;
        } catch (CASMismatchException e) {
            if (i == numCasRetries) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anything I'd argue that in this scenario the rx approach is less readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an operation on a single document where ultimately you need to block, I'd tend to agree that your second example is clearer.

RxJava shines when you heavily use asynchronous processing, especially when you need advanced error handling, retry scenarii, combination of asynchronous flows...

The previous generation of Couchbase Java SDK (1.4.x) just had `Future` for that, and it didn't provide the elegant, powerful and expressive capabilities we found in RxJava.